# Docker image for compute engine that contains selenium, chrome and chromedriver not working properly

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to build a Docker image which scrapes a web page with selenium. The python code for scraping is as follows:

```
# Configurar las opciones del navegador
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# Crear el controlador de Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Acceder a la página web
driver.get(link)

# Obtener el contenido de la página
page_source = driver.page_source

# Crear el objeto BeautifulSoup para analizar el contenido de la página
pagesoup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

# Cerrar el controlador de Selenium
driver.quit()
```

My actual dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Instalar dependencias de Selenium y Chrome
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget curl unzip gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Descargar y configurar ChromeDriver
ARG CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=96.0.4664.45
RUN wget -qO- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip | \
    zcat > /usr/local/bin/chromedriver && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Copiar archivos de la aplicación Dash
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY main.py .

# Crear los directorios necesarios
RUN mkdir -p /app/pages /app/assets/icons

# Copiar archivos adicionales
COPY pages /app/pages/
COPY app/assets /app/assets/

# Instalar requisitos
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Variables de entorno y comando de inicio
ENV DISPLAY=:99
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Comando de inicio
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

And I keep getting this error: (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Note: I don't want to use headless mode in chrome.